# How to edit Text in Memo?

Tags: delphi, text, lines, tmemo

I wanted to use procedure **Delete**(*Memo.Text*, index, count) (or similar **Insert**). But I get message 'Constant object can not be passed as var parameter'. I know I can select text and to use this procedures with **Seltext**. But this way is a bit uncomfortable. Is there anything easier?

Comment: Nope. Memo.Text is a getter, not a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Text` is a property rather than a variable. And `Delete` requires a variable. So you need to use a temporary variable. For instance

```
var
  str: string;
.... 
str := Memo1.Text;
Delete(str, index, count);
Memo1.Text := str;
```

Comment: For the case in the question (to have the text of the memo modified) the alternative mentioned in the question (using seltext) is better. The api handles the change rather than the framework retrieving the whole text, modifying, and then re-setting.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call [`System.Delete()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Delete), which takes a **reference to a `string` variable** as input.  But `TMemo.Text` is a **property** (that uses a getter method), it is not a **variable**.  That is why you are getting the "can not be passed as var parameter" error.

You *could* use a temporary variable, eg:

```
var 
  s: string;

s := Memo.Text;
Delete(s, index, count);
Memo.Text := s;
```

But this is very inefficient in general, as it has to make a complete copy of the Memo's current content in memory, then modify/reallocate it, and then reassign it back to the Memo, completely wiping the current content and parsing the new content.  That is a lot of work for small changes.

A faster and more efficient choice is to use the Memo's `SelStart`/`SelLength` and `SelText` properties instead, eg:

```
Memo.SelStart := index;
Memo.SelLength := count;
Memo.SelText := '';
```

You can do the same when inserting new text, just set `SelLength` to 0 instead, eg:

```
Memo.SelStart := index;
Memo.SelLength := 0;
Memo.SelText := 'text to insert';
```

Using these properties may be "uncomfortable", but it really is a good choice, from memory and performance perspectives.  Internally, they simply send Win32 `EM_(GET|SET|REPLACE)SEL` messages directly to the Memo's window, letting the OS handle the actual text management.

If you really want the most efficient way, use the Win32 messages directly, eg:

```
//delete
Memo.Perform(EM_SETSEL, index, index+count);
Memo.Perform(EM_REPLACESEL, 0, LPARAM(PChar('')));
```

```
//insert
Memo.Perform(EM_SETSEL, index, index);
Memo.Perform(EM_REPLACESEL, 0, LPARAM(PChar('text to insert')));
```